# Guava Splitter to produce as map with set value

Tags: guava

What's the best way to convert a string below into a `Map <Key, Set<String>>` using Guava `Splitter`?

```
String pairs = "cat:01,02,03;dog:AA,BB,CC;fish:A1,A2";
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
String pairs = "cat:01,02,03;dog:AA,BB,CC;fish:A1,A2";
Map<String, Set<String>> pairMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

Map<String, String> map = Splitter.on(';')
        .withKeyValueSeparator(':')
        .split(pairs);

map.forEach((key, value) -> {
    pairMap.put(key, Splitter.on(',').splitToList(value).stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()));
});

pairMap.forEach((key, valueSet) ->{
    System.out.println("key: "+key);
    valueSet.forEach(value ->{
        System.out.println(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sure, why don't you try it?

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your response.

Comment: @JBNizet https://github.com/nkumarclm/test/blob/master/sample.java is the one I tried. thinking is there a better way to do the same with splitter library more effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is mostly correct, there's no API in Guava's Splitter to parse values in a specific manner, so you have to iterate twice (unless you decide to drop `MapSplitter` and just use `Splitter` with your own values parsing in a loop).

That said, there's handy collection ala `Map<Foo, Collection<Bar>>`, which is [`Multimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/26.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) -- in your case `SetMultimap` (preferably [`ImmutableSetMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/26.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetMultimap.html)), ex.:

```
String pairs = "cat:01,02,03;dog:AA,BB,CC;fish:A1,A2";

Map<String, String> map = Splitter.on(';')
    .withKeyValueSeparator(':')
    .split(pairs);

ImmutableSetMultimap<String, String> pairMap = map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(ImmutableSetMultimap.flatteningToImmutableSetMultimap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> Streams.stream(Splitter.on(',').split(e.getValue()))));

System.out.println(pairMap);
// {cat=[01, 02, 03], dog=[AA, BB, CC], fish=[A1, A2]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear edits. Your answer clarifies everything :)